# java enum new list creation is not working as expected

Tags: java, list, enums

Ok this has stumped me, maybe I am missing something.

I have got an enum type list and I am trying to remove the duplicates. And in the below code , I am not able to create a new list as the list is emptied during the iteration.

Can anybody spot the issue.

```
List<UserRole> newList = new ArrayList<UserRole>();

for (UserRole userRole: originalList)
{           
        boolean found = false;

        logger.trace("size of new list: check1 = "+newList.size());   <-- size resets to 0

        for (UserRole newRole: newList)
        {
            logger.trace("check "+userRole.name()+ " with "+newRole.name());
            if (StringUtils.equals(newRole.name(),userRole.name()))
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!found)
        {               
            newList.add(userRole);
            logger.trace("size of new list check2= "+newList.size());
        }
}
return newList;
```

the UserRole enum class looks like

```
public enum UserRole {

SYSADMIN,
ADMIN,
STUDENT,
TEACHER,
PRINCIPAL;

public String value() {
    return name();
}

public static UserRole fromValue(String v) {
    return valueOf(v);
}

}
```

the trace log

```
20:20:22.291 TRACE  44 removeDuplicates - size of new list check1 = 0
20:20:22.291 TRACE  57 removeDuplicates - checking duplicate passed for role = SYSADMIN
20:20:22.291 TRACE  59 removeDuplicates - size of new list check2 = 1
20:20:22.295 TRACE  44 removeDuplicates - size of new list check1 = 0
20:20:22.295 TRACE  57 removeDuplicates - checking duplicate passed for role = SYSADMIN
20:20:22.295 TRACE  59 removeDuplicates - size of new list check2 = 1
20:20:22.296 TRACE  44 removeDuplicates - size of new list check1 = 0
20:20:22.296 TRACE  57 removeDuplicates - checking duplicate passed for role = SYSADMIN
20:20:22.296 TRACE  59 removeDuplicates - size of new list check2 = 1
20:20:22.298 TRACE  44 removeDuplicates - size of new list check1 = 0
20:20:22.298 TRACE  57 removeDuplicates - checking duplicate passed for role = SYSADMIN
20:20:22.298 TRACE  59 removeDuplicates - size of new list check2 = 1
```

Comment: This code works. The problem must be elsewhere. http://ideone.com/T2WryH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Not a bug - Works for Me***  *#8>P*

I copied your code into a simple testing class and - *lo and behold!* - it works!

I did have to assume a bit of code that you didn't show, which is the context in which the `removeDuplicates(List<UserRole> originalList)` is being called that yields the logging output you gave. Since I don't see the problem you do, I can only think that you're problem is in the caller, not the method. Which, if I'm right, explains why you can't find the problem *in* the method - it would be *around* the call to the method.

If this "look over there" advice isn't enough to get you towards solution, please edit and include the calling code.

PS - Another approach to solving this is to use a *set theoretic* algorithm, like:

```
public static List<UserRole> removeDupesBySetTheory(final List<UserRole> originalList)
{
    final Set<UserRole> holdingSet = new HashSet<>();

    holdingSet.addAll(originalList);

    final List<UserRole> newList = new ArrayList<>();

    newList.addAll(holdingSet);

    return newList;
}
```

Which will give you the results you want in a different way - does that also show the problem? If so, then I *realllly* suggest you focus on the caller, not the callee. If you get different results, then you are right to keep looking at your method internals (despite your code working for me).

PPS - If you want `removeDupesBySetTheory` to preserve the relative ordering of the original list, then use `final Set<UserRole> holdingSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();`

Comment: `EnumSet` would be much better than `HashSet`. If original order is required, use `LinkedHashSet`.

Comment: Thanks ......for pointing out to my calling code. All of the answers were helpful, but yours gave me a hint.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas (and others) who remind me of the `EnumSet` option - I somehow always forget about that specialization (along with `EnumMap`). Maybe now it will stick. Too bad we don't have `LinkedEnumSet` so we could use it directly even when original order (sans dupes) is wanted (and `LinkedEnumMap`, too).

Answer (score 2):

The display code does *not* reset the new list on each iteration.

However, you should not be using a `List` of enum values. Use [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) instead.

Being a `Set`, it will automatically prevent duplicates.

Unlike `List` or `LinkedHashSet`, where order is insertion-order, and `HashSet`, where order is arbitrary, `EnumSet` will order same as the sequence in which the enum values are defined.

Also, `EnumSet` is compact and has very nice helper methods for working with enums:

- `EnumSet.copyOf(originalList)` **Easy way to do what you're trying**
- `EnumSet.allOf(UserRole.class)`
- `EnumSet.noneOf(UserRole.class)`
- `EnumSet.of(UserRole.STUDENT, UserRole.TEACHER)`
- `EnumSet.complementOf(EnumSet.of(UserRole.SYSADMIN))` *All enums, except `SYSADMIN`*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really able to reproduce your exact issue, but if you are just trying to remove duplicates you can use a `Set` instead of an `List`.

```
Set<UserRole> mySet = EnumSet.noneOf(UserRole.class);

mySet.add(UserRole.SYSADMIN);
mySet.add(UserRole.SYSADMIN);
mySet.add(UserRole.SYSADMIN);
mySet.add(UserRole.TEACHER);

System.out.println(mySet);
```

With an output of:

```
[SYSADMIN, TEACHER]
```

Comment: `EnumSet` would be much better than `HashSet`.

Comment: I don't agree with either. I'd use `LinkedHashSet` to retain order.

Comment: @PaulBoddington If order is important, I'd agree. For enums it rarely is, but as so often is the case, it depends. ;-)

Comment: I don't think order is important in this case, but if it is a `LinkedHashSet` would be appropriate. Can you modify an `EnumSet` easily? It appears to me that the use case is that roles will be added and removed, and thus need to be deduplicated.

Comment: @BooRadley [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) is a full `Set` implementation (extends `AbstractSet<E>`). They are just constructed differently.

Comment: @Andreas Good to know, I have updated my answer to use an `EnumSet`.